# Applying parseInt on array yields weird result

Tags: javascript

Trying to run a simple javascript to parse single digit ints in a string as follows:

```
var s = "22123222222213123212322123213222";
var a = s.split("");
var b = a.map(parseInt);
console.log(b);
[2, NaN, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Why is there a NaN for element with index 1?

Fiddle in the console here:
https://jsfiddle.net/po6oy1ws/

**EDIT**

After getting the correct answer below I felt I had to lookup this "map(Number)" business. Turns out Mozilla has a "gotcha" clause concerning this specific case. [Mozilla gotcha case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case)

Comment: `a.map(x => x|0);` https://jsfiddle.net/po6oy1ws/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parseInt` has two parameters

> parseInt(string, radix);

And `map`'s callback accepts three parameters:

> map(currentValue, index, array)

Therefore the `index` of the `currentValue` was passed as a `radix` to the `parseInt` function. Use `parseInt` with radix explicitly:

```
var s = "22123222222213123212322123213222";
var a = s.split("");
var b = a.map(e => parseInt(e, 10));
```

Or use `Number` instead of `parseInt`:

```
var s = "22123222222213123212322123213222";
var a = s.split("");
var b = a.map(Number);
```

Comment: `a.map` passes the array's value, index, and the array itself in that order to `parseInt` (or in the case of this answer, `Number`). Ergo why `radix` is important to note.

Comment: `.map()` provides the index (0, 1, 2, ...) that's used as the `radix`.